# Can't catch Doctrine event with FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to catch any Doctrine event while submitting the profile form. My event looks like this:

```
testevent:
    class: AppBundle\Event\TestListener
    arguments: ['@service_container']
    tags:
      - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber }
      - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist, method: prePersist, connection: default }
```

And my event which for now, should log and exit the app, while dumping the curent entity:

```
class TestListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct(\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function prePersist(\Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs $args){
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $this->container->get('logger')->info('asdasd');
        echo '<pre>';
        \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($entity); exit;
        echo '</pre>';

    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'onPrePersist'

        );
    }
}
```

I've tried postPersist, preFlush, postFlush, none are being thrown. However, they are being thrown on other forms made by me, so it has to be with FOSUserBundle, maybe?

Looking at the controller, it calls

```
  $userManager->updateUser($user);
```

which goes as

```
public function updateUser(UserInterface $user, $andFlush = true)
{
    $this->updateCanonicalFields($user);
    $this->updatePassword($user);

    $this->objectManager->persist($user);
    if ($andFlush) {
        $this->objectManager->flush();
    }
}
```

And the object manager is declared in the bundle like so:

```
<service id="fos_user.object_manager" class="Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager" public="false">
    <argument>%fos_user.model_manager_name%</argument>
</service>
```

Could it be that this manager is not calling Doctrine events? How can I make it call them?

Comment: why are you trying to register your `TestListener` as a subscriber and listener? I think what you want here is just the subscriber, so remove `- { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist, method: prePersist, connection: default }` and in your `getSubscribedEvents()` method, the event `onPrePersist` is incorrect, it should be [prePersist](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Events.php#L67)

Comment: Even with those changes it's still not working. It only works when I explicitly call persist myself somewhere else, but when modifying the profile here it doesn't trigger.

Comment: maybe your subscriber is being registered after the FOSUserBundle? try to move your Bundle in AppKernel before FOSUserBundle?

Comment: The bundle was already before FOSUB.